# How to set itemController in each as (ember 1.11 beta3)?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, each

I want to try use:

```
{{#each content as |product index|}}
  {{index}}
{{/each}}
```

But my app has the itemContoller, like this:

```
{{#each product in content itemController='product'}}
```

If I set this:

```
{{#each content as |product index| itemController='product'}}
```

It doesn't work! I found all of the ember guides and did not find the answer.

Any help please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Controllers (`Object`, `Array` and `itemController`) are going away. The new way to do things is by using a component.

So, instead of your item controller, you would define a component:

```
App.MyProductComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  myIndex: function(){
    return this.get('passedIndex') + 1;
  }.property('passedIndex')
});
```

Then, inside your `#each` helper you would use it as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each model as |product index|}}
      {{ my-product passedIndex=index product=product }}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lixebi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

See the following link and do a search for `itemController` - https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15

Comment: Don't forget to set `tagName: 'li'` in the component. Otherwise, a div will be used, which could mess up your list.

Answer (score 0):

Really? I mean, there are many cases where I think creating a component for displaying computed values based on the property(s) of the controller's model would be overkill..... What if I just want a *string* (I don't need the `<div>` thing added by ember for each component).

Creating helper(s) then? Wow.

Answer (score 0):

@user3443096,

If you wouldn't like to have div tags inserted by ember use `tagName: ""` property like this:

```
App.InvoiceItemsComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
tagName: '' 
});
```

Now, divs around your component will not be inserted.